# Geting Subquery result based on other subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have a Query, that I need to use subqueries.

A simple example of what I want

```
Select (Subquery1 S1) as UserId,
       ,(Subquery2 S2 where Id = UserID )
Inner Join Table 3
Inner Join Table 4
```

this is very generic, and the query I have, is working for all the columns except thos in Subquery2. I need to have, in that column, the username. So I'm querying a users table, where ID = UserId, from the previous column...

Can I achieve this? I need that the query runs based on the userID result...
How?

Comment: Yes,JOIN on your subquery and give it an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of joining 2 subqueries I would `JOIN` 2 CTE.

Your code will look something like this.

```
;WITH   QueryA
          AS (
               SELECT UserID
                FROM MyTableA
             ),
        QueryB
          AS (
               SELECT MyData
                   ,ID
                FROM MyTableB
             )
    SELECT *
        FROM QueryA AS a
        JOIN QueryB AS b
            ON a.UserID = b.ID
```

CTEs will give you much better readability and better execution plans. Once you have CTE you treat it as just another table that you can join to.

You can read more on CTEs at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
SELECT
  (SELECT TOP 1 UserID FROM UsersTable1 WHERE UserID = 1) AS UserID,
  (SELECT TOP 1 UserData u2 FROM UsersTable2 u2 INNER JOIN UsersTable1 u1 ON U1.UserId = u2.UserID)
  ....
  ...
  ..
  .
  (rest of your code)
```